# Multiple Monitors with Ubuntu 15.10 and LenovoW521 on a Docking station

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, docking

I have been fighting with setting up multiple monitors on my Lenovo using a docking station.
In the end things work how I want them (two external monitors + laptop screen next to each other) but:

- when I remove the laptop from the station and re-attach it, it does not detect the external monitors automatically. I have to log out and in again (basically, restart X) to have them available
- upon login the configuration gets lost and the monitors are not in the order I want them
- If I simply switch the position of my monitors in display settings, it gives me an error like "GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gsd_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code2: could not set the configuration for CRTC 63". I need to select "mirror displays", then apply, then untick mirror displays and rearrange the monitors to the correct position in order to get the desired outcome

Doing this ritual every day is getting annoying and I especially would like to be able to continue from yesterday instead of having to log in and out every morning. Is there a solution to this issue? There are a lot of questions asked here around this topic but none of them seem to apply for this particular issue.

I get the following message when logging in and the configuration is reset:

Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors
could not set the configuration for CRTC 65

Comment: Same problem here